# Mouseover Background Movement

Tags: jquery, css, mousemove

I am trying to get subtle movement when the mouse hovers over a div.

However, the subtlety part of that isn't quite working out.

As soon as you hover over, the background image jumps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var movementStrength = 50;
    var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
    var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
    $("#bg").mousemove(function(e){
              var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
              var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
              var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
              var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
              $('#bg').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjnLtcr0/2/

Comment: you want a delay or a slight move?

Comment: I'm looking for slight movement

Comment: can you try `newvalueX / 5 + "px     "+newvalueY / 5 +"px"`

Comment: I tried that and it helps a bit. I am using this on a responsive theme. So it helps when the width of the window is 250px but not so on any other window. I'm thinking it has to do with the ratio of the stretched background image.

Comment: it might get complicated if you want the image to slide slowly instead of jump when first hover happens.

Comment: it jumps because the image depends on the mouse position and your exit and entry coordinates are different most of the time. Your code works. What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Is it possible to slowly move to the new coordinates as opposed to jumping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class with a transition, use a timeout to wait for the transition to end, and then remove the class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 50;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  $("#bg").on({
    mouseenter: function(e) { // on mouse enter
      var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
      var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
      var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
      var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;

      $('#bg').addClass('transition'); // add a transition

      $('#bg').css({ // move background with transition
        "background-position": newvalueX + "px     " + newvalueY + "px"
      });

      setTimeout(function() { // wait .3s
        $('#bg').removeClass('transition'); // remove the transition
      }, 300);
    },

    mousemove: function(e) { // on mouse move
      var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
      var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
      var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
      var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;

      if ($('#bg').hasClass('transition')) { // if there is a transition
        //wait for above timeout to remove transition
      } else { // else no transition

        $('#bg').css({ // move the background without transition
          "background-position": newvalueX + "px     " + newvalueY + "px"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#bg {
  background: url('http://netsketched.com/pandf/img/sun-rise-clouds.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 100px;
}
.transition {
  /*class with transition*/
  transition: all .3s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg">
  <h2>Hello, world!</h2>
</div>
```

[Documentation for setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)